# Output valid xml when executing mvn help:effective-pom

Tags: xml, maven, maven-3

When I execute `mvn help:effective-pom` it also outputs `[INFO] ...` to stdout. Surpressing it via `-q` outputs nothing at all when dealing with correct files so

I want to pipe the effective pom into xmlstarlet to get the effective properties but as the output isn't a valid xml it fails.

A request for my usecase was closed as a wontfix (at least to my understanding) at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPH-23 .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use output property:

> mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=< FILE >

Comment: I've misread the docs. I thought it will just write the output you get to a file. But as all the log statements come from maven itself and not the plugin, the output file is clear from such cruft. Do you know of a way to surpress mvn log statements and write only the plugin result to stdout?

Comment: With this, the script to get the properties is reduced to to `mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective.pom && xml sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -c "/x:project/x:properties" effective.pom`. It leaves effective.pom in your working directory though.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround

```
mvn help:effective-pom | grep -v '\[INFO\|\[WARNING\|Downloading' | sed '1,2d' | xml sel -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -c "/x:project/x:properties"
```

will output the properties as xml.

You need [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

```
brew install xmlstarlet #OSX
apt-get install xmlstarlet
```